# what were the last few queries ran on SQL Server ?

Tags: sql-server

what were the last few queries ran on SQL Server and with client name (system name) ? 
i am running this query in server side
below query getting queries

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

how can i get system name

for e.g 
  time | query | System Name

Comment: dm_exec_query_stats and dm_exec_sql_text contains overall info about queries. This queries cound be run already millions of times before from different clients, so no specific client info could be stored in this dmv's.

Comment: Ya but i need client system name ...? how can i get it...?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible from SQL Server itself by default. It would be waste of resources to capture and store/manage all data about every single query (not overall info). But i suggest you can just use SQL Profiler to capture all activity you are intersting in.

Comment: ya thank for your information .....we have installed sql server 2012. by default profiler is not present on it...

Comment: Worth noting that Profiler has been officially deprecated and will not be in future versions of SQL server.  It has been replaced by extended events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below query should help you:

```
SELECT conn.session_id, sson.host_name, sson.login_name, 
     sqltxt.text, sson.login_time,  sson.status
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections conn
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions sson 
ON conn.session_id = sson.session_id
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(most_recent_sql_handle) AS sqltxt
ORDER BY conn.session_id desc
```

Source: http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2011/12/last-run-query-in-sql-server.html

Answer (score 2):

You could check the sp_who and sp_who2 text.

```
create procedure sys.sp_who2  --- 1995/11/03 10:16
    @loginame     sysname = NULL
as

set nocount on

declare
    @retcode         int

declare
    @sidlow         varbinary(85)
   ,@sidhigh        varbinary(85)
   ,@sid1           varbinary(85)
   ,@spidlow         int
   ,@spidhigh        int

declare
    @charMaxLenLoginName      varchar(6)
   ,@charMaxLenDBName         varchar(6)
   ,@charMaxLenCPUTime        varchar(10)
   ,@charMaxLenDiskIO         varchar(10)
   ,@charMaxLenHostName       varchar(10)
   ,@charMaxLenProgramName    varchar(10)
   ,@charMaxLenLastBatch      varchar(10)
   ,@charMaxLenCommand        varchar(10)

declare
    @charsidlow              varchar(85)
   ,@charsidhigh             varchar(85)
   ,@charspidlow              varchar(11)
   ,@charspidhigh             varchar(11)

-- defaults

select @retcode         = 0      -- 0=good ,1=bad.
select @sidlow = convert(varbinary(85), (replicate(char(0), 85)))
select @sidhigh = convert(varbinary(85), (replicate(char(1), 85)))

select
    @spidlow         = 0
   ,@spidhigh        = 32767

--------------------------------------------------------------
IF (@loginame IS     NULL)  --Simple default to all LoginNames.
      GOTO LABEL_17PARM1EDITED

-- select @sid1 = suser_sid(@loginame)
select @sid1 = null
if exists(select * from sys.syslogins where loginname = @loginame)
    select @sid1 = sid from sys.syslogins where loginname = @loginame

IF (@sid1 IS NOT NULL)  --Parm is a recognized login name.
   begin
   select @sidlow  = suser_sid(@loginame)
         ,@sidhigh = suser_sid(@loginame)
   GOTO LABEL_17PARM1EDITED
   end

--------

IF (lower(@loginame collate Latin1_General_CI_AS) IN ('active'))  --Special action, not sleeping.
   begin
   select @loginame = lower(@loginame collate Latin1_General_CI_AS)
   GOTO LABEL_17PARM1EDITED
   end

--------

IF (patindex ('%[^0-9]%' , isnull(@loginame,'z')) = 0)  --Is a number.
   begin
   select
             @spidlow   = convert(int, @loginame)
            ,@spidhigh  = convert(int, @loginame)
   GOTO LABEL_17PARM1EDITED
   end

--------

raiserror(15007,-1,-1,@loginame)
select @retcode = 1
GOTO LABEL_86RETURN


LABEL_17PARM1EDITED:


--------------------  Capture consistent sysprocesses.  -------------------

select

  spid
 ,status
 ,sid
 ,hostname
 ,program_name
 ,cmd
 ,cpu
 ,physical_io
 ,blocked
 ,dbid
 ,convert(sysname, rtrim(loginame))
        as loginname
 ,spid as 'spid_sort'

 ,  substring( convert(varchar,last_batch,111) ,6  ,5 ) + ' '
  + substring( convert(varchar,last_batch,113) ,13 ,8 )
       as 'last_batch_char'
 ,request_id

      into    #tb1_sysprocesses
      from sys.sysprocesses_ex with (nolock)

if @@error <> 0
    begin
        select @retcode = @@error
        GOTO LABEL_86RETURN
    end

--------Screen out any rows?

if (@loginame in ('active'))
   delete #tb1_sysprocesses
         where   lower(status)  = 'sleeping'
         and     upper(cmd)    in (
                     'AWAITING COMMAND'
                    ,'LAZY WRITER'
                    ,'CHECKPOINT SLEEP'
                                  )

         and     blocked       = 0



--------Prepare to dynamically optimize column widths.


select
    @charsidlow     = convert(varchar(85),@sidlow)
   ,@charsidhigh    = convert(varchar(85),@sidhigh)
   ,@charspidlow     = convert(varchar,@spidlow)
   ,@charspidhigh    = convert(varchar,@spidhigh)



select
             @charMaxLenLoginName =
                  convert( varchar
                          ,isnull( max( datalength(loginname)) ,5)
                         )

            ,@charMaxLenDBName    =
                  convert( varchar
                          ,isnull( max( datalength( rtrim(convert(varchar(128),db_name(dbid))))) ,6)
                         )

            ,@charMaxLenCPUTime   =
                  convert( varchar
          ,isnull( max( datalength( rtrim(convert(varchar(128),cpu)))) ,7)
                         )

            ,@charMaxLenDiskIO    =
                  convert( varchar
                          ,isnull( max( datalength( rtrim(convert(varchar(128),physical_io)))) ,6)
                         )

            ,@charMaxLenCommand  =
                  convert( varchar
                          ,isnull( max( datalength( rtrim(convert(varchar(128),cmd)))) ,7)
                         )

            ,@charMaxLenHostName  =
                  convert( varchar
                          ,isnull( max( datalength( rtrim(convert(varchar(128),hostname)))) ,8)
                         )

            ,@charMaxLenProgramName =
                  convert( varchar
                          ,isnull( max( datalength( rtrim(convert(varchar(128),program_name)))) ,11)
                         )

            ,@charMaxLenLastBatch =
                  convert( varchar
                          ,isnull( max( datalength( rtrim(convert(varchar(128),last_batch_char)))) ,9)
                         )
      from
             #tb1_sysprocesses
      where
             spid >= @spidlow
      and    spid <= @spidhigh



--------Output the report.


EXEC(
'
SET nocount off

SELECT
             SPID          = convert(char(5),spid)

            ,Status        =
                  CASE lower(status)
                     When ''sleeping'' Then lower(status)
                     Else                   upper(status)
                  END

            ,Login         = substring(loginname,1,' + @charMaxLenLoginName + ')

            ,HostName      =
                  CASE hostname
                     When Null  Then ''  .''
                     When '' '' Then ''  .''
                     Else    substring(hostname,1,' + @charMaxLenHostName + ')
                  END

            ,BlkBy         =
                  CASE               isnull(convert(char(5),blocked),''0'')
                     When ''0'' Then ''  .''
                     Else            isnull(convert(char(5),blocked),''0'')
                  END

            ,DBName        = substring(case when dbid = 0 then null when dbid <> 0 then db_name(dbid) end,1,' + @charMaxLenDBName + ')
            ,Command       = substring(cmd,1,' + @charMaxLenCommand + ')

            ,CPUTime       = substring(convert(varchar,cpu),1,' + @charMaxLenCPUTime + ')
            ,DiskIO        = substring(convert(varchar,physical_io),1,' + @charMaxLenDiskIO + ')

            ,LastBatch     = substring(last_batch_char,1,' + @charMaxLenLastBatch + ')

            ,ProgramName   = substring(program_name,1,' + @charMaxLenProgramName + ')
            ,SPID          = convert(char(5),spid)  --Handy extra for right-scrolling users.
            ,REQUESTID       = convert(char(5),request_id)
      from
             #tb1_sysprocesses  --Usually DB qualification is needed in exec().
      where
             spid >= ' + @charspidlow  + '
      and    spid <= ' + @charspidhigh + '

      -- (Seems always auto sorted.)   order by spid_sort

SET nocount on
'
)


LABEL_86RETURN:


if (object_id('tempdb..#tb1_sysprocesses') is not null)
            drop table #tb1_sysprocesses

return @retcode -- sp_who2
```

Hope this helps.